# what happens if we do not close the used end in pipe: Linux/C

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

Suppose we have a pipe and the parent is writing on it and child is reading from the pipe. 
We know that the parent should close the reading end BEFORE writing and child should close the writing end BEFORE reading. 
But I want to know :
Is it mandatory to close the writing end after the parent is done with writing? and likewise, the child needs to close the reading end AFTER it is done with reading?
if it is mandatory, why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not mandatory, but you probably want to do it, especially on the **writing-end** of your pipe.

**Pipe-end filedescriptors** are counted references to **pipe-end entities** behind them. When you `dup` a **pipe-end filedescriptor** or when you fork a process with an open **pipe-end**, new references to the same **pipe-end entity** are created and the reference count increases (and each `close` decreases it).

For the closing of a **writing end** to turn into an **EOF** on the other end (usually desirable or else the consumer (**reading end**) won't know when to stop reading), that **writing-end filedescriptor** needs to be the last reference to the **writing-end entity**—a pipe's writing end is only considered closed if all references (filedescriptors) to that **writing-end entity** are closed.

(This behavior applies to all filedescriptors and isn't limited to pipe-end filedescriptors.)